# Inserindo índice e valor num array bidimensional

Tags: php, array, matriz, foreach, array-multidimensional

Tenho um array bidimensional (nele estão contidos dados vindo do banco de dados).
Para percorrer esses dados, utilizo um foreach(). 
Eu preciso adicionar um índice e um valor nesse índice no final de cada iteração do foreach().

Imaginando como se fosse uma matriz (linha x coluna), eu preciso inserir uma coluna no final de cada linha.
Segue o código abaixo:

```
foreach($dados as $d) {
    if($d['direta'] == 1 && ($d['idEntidade_evento'] == 0 && $d['idSemana'] == 0)){
        $d['tipo'] =& 'Mensagem instantânea';
    } else if($d['direta'] && $d['idEntidade_evento'] > 0 && $d['idSemana'] == 0){
        $d['tipo'] =& 'Evento';
    } else{
        $d['tipo'] =& 'Avaliação';
    }
}
```

No final, eu preciso que $dados contenha tudo (o novo índice inserido no foreach() )

No final, $dados não possui esse índice (não existe $dados['tipo']). É como se não fosse inserido nada.

Comment: Atualizei o post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer isso, modificando o elemento atual da iteração com o `&` ele alterar/adiciona o valor da variável por referência ou seja não faz um cópia um do original.

```
foreach($dados as &$d) {
   $d['nova_chave'] = rand(1,99);
}
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que eu entendi você só quer colocar uma nova coluna, então é bem simples:

```
foreach($dados as $indice => $d) {
    $dados[$indice]['nova_coluna'] = "Novo dado";
}
```